# Recover M-values from PostGIS `ST_Intersection`?

Tags: postgis, intersection, m-values

I am querying the intersection of a path (`LinestringZM`) through a region (`MultiPolygon`) but the `ST_Intersection` returns only the Lat/Long/Alt coordinates and I need to recover time, stored in the M values.

```
SELECT path.name AS path_name,
  ST_Length(path.geom::geography) AS distance,
  ST_Length(geography(ST_Intersection(path.geom,region.geom))) AS region_distance,
  ST_M(ST_EndPoint(path.geom)) - ST_M(ST_StartPoint(path.geom)) AS time,
  ST_M(ST_EndPoint(ST_Intersection(path.geom,region.geom))) - ST_M(ST_StartPoint(ST_Intersection(path.geom,region.geom))) AS region_time
  region.name AS region_name
FROM path INNER JOIN region ON ST_Intersects(path.geom, region.geom) 
ORDER BY vehicle_name, region_distance DESC;
```

How can I get the exact elapsed time within a region? (the above `region_time` is null because M coordinate is dropped. I was thinking of using `LATERAL` select to get the equivalent matching segment of the original path like so:
`ST_SharedPaths(path.geom,rel.intersection_path)`
...
`LATERAL (SELECT ST_Intersection(path.geom,region.geom) AS intersection_path) AS rel`

But that gives me `ERROR:  GEOSSharedPaths: TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING (...`

I'm using PostGIS 2.4 and PostgreSQL 10.1 beta, in case it matters.

Comment: `FROM path, region
WHERE ST_Intersects(path.geom, region.geom)` is older syntax that shouldn't be used. It was replaced over 20 years ago with `FROM path INNER JOIN region ON ST_Intersects(path.geom, region.geom)`

Comment: corrected, thanks -- it appears to run the query faster with explicit inner join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use several functions to do the deed which you can grab here
https://github.com/pauldzy/pg_dz_lrs/blob/master/Functions/LRS_INTERSECTION.sql

We could log an enhancement but I believe all the tepid M support derives from the underlying GEOS implementation.

Cheers,
Paul

Comment: Thanks, I ended up approximating the time with number of data points, since they're collected at regular intervals, but that looks like it might be useful.

Comment: OSGEO M Values support was merged to a branch and left there awaiting performance analysis and bug fixing, in case someone wants to have a go at it.
https://github.com/OSGeo/geos/pull/45